# Rails javascript asset missing after precompile

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, file, assets, pipeline

the [Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#highlighter_293656) says:

> If there are missing precompiled files in production you will get an
>   Sprockets::Helpers::RailsHelper::AssetPaths::AssetNotPrecompiledError
>   exception indicating the name of the missing file(s).

I do execute:

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

however I don't get any error, and my javascript file is missing in the *manifest.yml*. Also it's not appearing in *public/assets*, so the problem is only on production.

I have in the *application.js*

```
//= require formalize/jquery-formalize
```

What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: In development env, can you access `jquery-formalize` correct？

Comment: yes, in development I see it's working

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Actually two things needed to do:

```
config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js *.css )
```

as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6415449/rails-3-1-asset-pipeline-missing-files-from-public-assets-why-isnt-this-the), and

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

for local production testing when using

```
rail s
```

of course using

```
rake assets:precompile
```

however in my case - without config.assets.precompile this would have no effect since the manifest didn't contain any reference to my javascript file.

HTH.

Comment: Thanks, you saved me hours. I tried all of the above except ... "config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js *.css )". That did the trick

Comment: After 3 hours of similar issues where assets were available in Development, but not on Production... those two lines in production.rb saved me! Now Development and Production behave in the same manner!

Answer (score 5):

Try just:

```
rake assets:precompile
```

I've had similar issues and that has worked.
You can also delete the contents of the `/public/assets` directory and try running it again.