# Datatables not showing in production mode after running rake assets:precompile. rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatables, production-environment

When i run my application in development my [datatables](http://datatables.net) table is showing
but when i run my app in production datatables is not showing. only the records ar shown.

screenshot in developemnt:

[image: datatables showing]

screenshot in production:

[image: datatables missing]

My production.rb:

```
Contractbeheerpj::Application.configure do
  # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/application.rb

  # Code is not reloaded between requests
  config.cache_classes = true

  # Full error reports are disabled and caching is turned on
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true

  # Disable Rails's static asset server (Apache or nginx will already do this)
  config.serve_static_assets = false

  # Compress JavaScripts and CSS
  config.assets.compress = true

  # Don't fallback to assets pipeline if a precompiled asset is missed
  config.assets.compile = true

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = true

  # Defaults to nil and saved in location specified by config.assets.prefix
  # config.assets.manifest = YOUR_PATH

  # Specifies the header that your server uses for sending files
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = "X-Sendfile" # for apache
  # config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect' # for nginx

  # Force all access to the app over SSL, use Strict-Transport-Security, and use secure cookies.
  # config.force_ssl = true

  # See everything in the log (default is :info)
  # config.log_level = :debug

  # Prepend all log lines with the following tags
  # config.log_tags = [ :subdomain, :uuid ]

  # Use a different logger for distributed setups
  # config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(SyslogLogger.new)

  # Use a different cache store in production
  # config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store

  # Enable serving of images, stylesheets, and JavaScripts from an asset server
  # config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://assets.example.com"

  # Precompile additional assets (application.js, application.css, and all non-JS/CSS are already added)
  # config.assets.precompile += %w( search.js )

  # Disable delivery errors, bad email addresses will be ignored
  # config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

  # Enable threaded mode
  # config.threadsafe!

  # Enable locale fallbacks for I18n (makes lookups for any locale fall back to
  # the I18n.default_locale when a translation can not be found)
  config.i18n.fallbacks = true

  # Send deprecation notices to registered listeners
  config.active_support.deprecation = :notify

  # Log the query plan for queries taking more than this (works
  # with SQLite, MySQL, and PostgreSQL)
  # config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
end
```

Hope someone can help! :)

Comment: might be a problem of your assets. Try run `rake assets:precompile` and then restart the rails server!

Comment: ofcourse i ran rake assets:precompile. that not the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is probably because of Rails Asset pipelining which Rails in production precompiles your js files to public/assets hence your js file is either not loaded or is an older version. Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218740/rails-javascript-asset-missing-after-precompile/) to a similar issue to what you are having.

Comment: it takes more than an hour to compile the assets? what's the problem lololol

Comment: when i remove the line config.assets.precompile += %w( *.js *.css ) it compiles but no js files are compiled? why does it take so long

Comment: Did you find a solution? i didn't

Comment: i god. it worked. when i booted my pc this morning and tried again. thanks for the link :D