# Rails 3.2 - assets precompile, but not display in production mode with Apache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache2, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

***Edit:***
Turns out my initial question is no longer accurate - the issue isn't directly related to the dataTables gem, I believe it's to do with my Apache2 configuration.

---

I seem to have an issue with the jquery-datatables-rails gem playing nicely with the rails asset pipeline.

The problem at first appeared similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11408062/datatables-not-showing-in-production-mode-after-running-rake-assetsprecompile), but following the apparent path of solutions from there didn't happily resolve the issue.

The gem is in my Gemfile, installed and implemented for one of my html tables according to the directions in [railscast episode #340](http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables). Running the application in development mode with `bundle exec rails s` works just fine, and all of the dataTables features appear on the site with no problem.

When I try and run the site in a production environment - either using capistrano or just `bundle exec rails s -e production` - after precompiling the assets, the compiled files aren't used, though they do all compile to public/assets.

It also didn't seem to show dataTables features when using `config.assets.compile = true` in lieu of precompiling. (I believe the two are opposites, but I may have misunderstood)

There are no errors when I go to the page and view the js error console, it just renders a plan html table.

I can not figure out what's causing the webpage to **not** render dataTables, and every search I've tried has wound up at the question linked above plus some five other pages over and over again. None of those solutions seem to have been what my rails beast is hungering for.

Do any of you fine people have any insight as to what the problem might be?

---

Parts of some relevant files:

app/assets/javascripts/charts.js.coffee:

```
jQuery ->
    $('#charts').dataTable({
      "oSearch": {"bSmart": "true", "sSearch": "vdo"}
      "iDisplayLength": 50
     })
```

app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
//= require_self
//= require_tree .
```

app/assets/stylesheets/application.css

```
*= require_self      
*= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
*= require_tree .
```

config/environments/production.rb:
    PerfGrapher::Application.configure do
    # Settings specified here will take precedence over those in config/environment.rb

```
# Compress JavaScript and CSS
config.assets.compress = true

# make sure to compile js and css assets
config.assets.precompile += %w(*.js *.css)

# Generate digests for assets URLs
config.assets.digest = true

# disable static asset server
config.serve_static_assets = false

config.compile = false
```

end

Comment: Is your javascript call to dataTable() getting invoked in production? Can you put in a call to alert() or something similar to verify?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that to check - indeed the alert isn't popping up in production either, and this time my compiled things went to public/public/assets, which is not where they should be going (perhaps unrelated). I suppose this means my assets are just being ignored by rails, but I've no idea why...

Comment: What web server are you using? Apache?

Comment: Aye, I'm using Apache. Though the problem also occurs when I try running a production-mode server locally. (rails s -e production)

Answer (score 1):

My application.css.scss file has the following line

```
*= require dataTables/src/demo_table_jui
```

instead of

```
*= require dataTables/jquery.dataTables
```

This may only be because I'm using JQuery UI also (with bJQueryUI: true being passed to dataTable() in the coffeescript file)

It works fine in production, with the asset pipeline, using Rails 3.2.6.

Comment: Hm, I'm  not using jquery-ui, just standard dataTables. 


Though, I tried adding it in, but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Try not defining config.assets.prefix in production.rb and just letting it take the default value. It shouldn't matter, but somehow you're getting an extra "public" in the directory path

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that as well - (it was from a dead-end I'd followed previously) - it's gone now. I should edit the main question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a poor rubyist and no railsman (though I do groovy grails, yeah).
Anyway, since you say even an alert isn't called (hmm, it irks me that it's only in prod mode) I just wanted to ask if it helps to see if it's related to the way rails compiles the html file --- therefore I would have loved to see the html file, to see if all the scripts are added in the header ...

I just think it might be due to the dom already loaded when your chart.js.js is executed.

To see if it is related to this at all, try replacing

```
jQuery ->
    $('#charts').dataTable({
      "oSearch": {"bSmart": "true", "sSearch": "vdo"}
      "iDisplayLength": 50
     })
```

with something like

```
imReadyToStart = () ->
    $('#charts').dataTable({
      "oSearch": {"bSmart": "true", "sSearch": "vdo"}
      "iDisplayLength": 50
     })
setTimeOut imReadyToStart, 1000
```

Comment: The scripts should be loaded through the application.js - there is sort of a 'main' html file which requires all of the scripts/plug-ins, then each individual html file gets plunked in depending where you are. The fact it's working in dev makes it seem like all of the connections are right, but it's failing on the file finding.

Comment: That said, I'm giving your suggestion a shot